# how do I set the hung_task_timeout_secs parameter?

Tags: 18.04, kernel, lubuntu, shutdown

how do I set the hung_task_timeout_secs for /proc/sys/kernel

Answer (score 0):

It is writable by root, so:

```
doug@s18:~$ ls -l /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep  1 07:20 /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs
doug@s18:~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs
120
doug@s18:~$ echo 130 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs
130
doug@s18:~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs
130
```